# Free image gallery extension for Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am looking for a free image gallery extension which I can integrate in Joomla 1.5.  Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Regards
Ramji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to start is the Joomla Extensions Directory.  It currently has 42 (!) offerings in the category of "photo gallery", most of which are free.  [Check them out](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery).

If you don't know which to choose, start with the [Very Simple Image Gallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery/6301); it may well do just what you need (you haven't specified any detailed requirements).